# How hazardous is a cellular base station-antenna to our health?

Tags: cancer, physical-health, bioelectromagnetics, cellular-phone

A telephone company is installing a cell tower (cellular base station-antenna) 40 meters from my house (right in front of my house). The first thing I am concerning about is its effect to our health. My neighbors are worried as well. So I'd like to know **How much hazardous is cell tower to our health?**

I am not an expert in the field but I know enough to understand that magnetic field the antenna is going to generate will certainly expose some amount of hazard to our health.

I read at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_radiation_and_health#Health_hazards_of_base_stations) that World Health Organization's International Agency for Research on Cancer classified electromagnetic fields from mobile phones and other sources as "possibly carcinogenic to humans". Some national radiation advisory authorities, including those of Austria, France, Germany, and Sweden, have recommended measures to minimize exposure to their citizens.

"Effects studied" section of the Wikipedia page addresses several issues like  *Blood–brain barrier*, *Cancer*, *Male fertility*, *Electromagnetic hypersensitivity*, *Glucose metabolism* which are really scary to read about.

**Can anyone answer if installing cell tower too close to population settlement creates hazard to health?**

Many thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: It seems your prior research has already answered your question. The WHO can't give a definitive answer because it's not settled science, and therefore neither can anyone here.

Comment: First of all, IARC is not WHO. In fact, the two organizations sometimes disagree with each other as in the case of glyphosate. While IARC is, in fact, an organization within WHO, it does not represent WHO. It is a misrepresentation to say that WHO said such-and-such, because IARC made that declaration. This said, I often hear the media making this very claim, which is...well...inaccurate.

Comment: @Carey Gregory. You say "The WHO can't give a definitive answer because it's not settled science" but neither it says "IT IS SAFE".

Comment: Nor does it say it's unsafe. If you're looking for confirmation of your fears or assurances that your fears are unfounded then I'm afraid you're not going to find either one from any reputable source now and probably not for a few more years at least.

Comment: While it may not be able to be answered definitively yet, +1 for providing some prior research and therefore asking a valid and interesting question

Answer (score 5):

While there has been some research showing that exposure to a large amount of non ionizing radiation can be harmful, at this time there is no definitive research showing that this exposure is definitely harmful.

Exposure to radio frequency energy is measured in SAR (specific absorption rate) In the US, [the FCC requires](https://transition.fcc.gov/oet/info/documents/bulletins/oet65/oet65.pdf)* that a transmitting facility take action to limit the exposure of the general public to 0.08W/kg. Workers who are in direct contact with transmission equipment may have exposure of up to 0.4W/kg. [One of the sources linked](https://www.scielo.br/j/ibju/a/Rg9yjCFyL3bHTwcLy8nGMsp/?lang=en) on Wikipedia showing a decrease in sperm motility and viability was looking at exposure levels of 1.46W/kg and 27.5W/kg, over 18 times the limit for general population exposure.

[Another study](https://ntp.niehs.nih.gov/whatwestudy/topics/cellphones/index.html) looking at cancer risk in rodents was measuring levels between 1.5W/kg and 10W/kg. Even at these levels, ["it was unclear if any of these tumor increases were related to [radio frequency exposure]"](https://www.nih.gov/news-events/news-releases/high-exposure-radiofrequency-radiation-linked-tumor-activity-male-rats)

*: Limits defined on page 75, guidelines for controlling exposure are pages 52 to 59